# VB.NET split string with quotation marks in it

Tags: vb.net, string, split

Trying to split a line wherever `","` appears (*with* the quotation marks). The problem is VB.NET uses `"` to start/end strings, so I tried using `.Split(""",""")` but that then splits it by `"` not `","`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Dim TestToSplit As String = "Foo"",""Bar"
Dim Splitted() As String = TestToSplit.Split(New String() {""","""}, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

I just tested it and got an array with Foo And Bar. I hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect! now all my numbers are wrong but I expected that. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

The Split function (the way you are using it) expects a Char. If you want to split on multiple characters you need to use a string **array**. (Seems to me another overload of a single string value would have been handy.)

This function splits a line of text and returns an array based on the delimiter you have specified. (Of course, you could make this more general purpose by passing in the separator array.)

```
   Private Function SplitLine(ByVal lineOfText As String) As String()

      Dim separator() As String = {""","""}
      Dim result() As String

      result = lineOfText.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.None)

      Return result

   End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative I often find useful is this:

```
Regex.Split(textToSplit, """,""")
```

Lets you split on more complex criteria than an array of alternative separators.

Answer (score 0):

To escape the "-character in VB.NET, use two: ""